# How to disable SQL Query echo in Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I have create module for testing in Magento and i call change action url from browser and there SQL query for catalog/product is printed.

I user this code

```
<?php
class Test_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

public function indexAction()
{
$this->loadLayout();     
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('capacityweb/Test','Test',array('template' => 'capacity/web/test.phtml'));
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
$this->renderLayout();
}

public function changeAction()
{
$this->loadLayout();     
$this->renderLayout();

$action=$this->getRequest()->getParam('action');        
$id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');


if($action!=null && $id!=null)
{
$relContact = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load($id);   
}


}

}
```

if i use

$relContact = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load($id);

then magento display SQL query but instead of this

i use

```
$relContact = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

then magento not display anything.

So how to fix issue with

```
$relContact = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading your code, I think what you are trying to do is load one product, in this case you have the $id.
In this case you should use:

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)
```

And then you can access the desire data through:

```
   $product->getName();
   $product->getDescription()
```

... and so on.

Greetings

Comment: i want read one product and also want to change ... but i think using this way i can read only, but not change or update product attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue.
Magento uses the Lazy Loading design pattern for collections.
The sql for a collection is not executed until the collection is loaded or until you iterate through the results.
So `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()` will return an object that is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` that you can use how you need, but you don't have the products yet.
When calling `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load()` (by the way...the `$id` parameter is useless), then the query `SELECT FROM catalog_product_entity.....` is exectuted and in `$collection->getIterator()` you will have the records from the database as instances of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`.
**[EDIT]**
If you want a single product skip the `getCollection` call. You can get the instance of a product like this

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
//changes some attributes
$product->setData('description', $description);
//or
//$product->setDescription($description);
$product->save().
```

[See more details about it here](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2009/11/import-simple-products-for-barrmy.html).

Comment: i want single product from database and change its attributes then any other way for it

Comment: try this $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE); this is not working with this model